# auto overwrite object with ObjectOutputStream

Tags: java, object

When i save a second object, and the first one is deleted from the file, how can i solve this?

```
public void guardar(){ 
    try {
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new 
        FileOutputStream("Datos.obj"));
        Object O[] = new Object[5];
        O[0] = getRfc();
        O[1] = getNombre();
        O[2] = getEdad();
        O[3] = getPuesto();
        O[4] = getSalario();
        oos.writeObject(O);
        oos.flush();
        oos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(datos.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(datos.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }   
}
```

Thanks in advance if someone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to read the file with the first object array. Then create a `java.util.ArrayList` of object arrays and save first the first object array into it, then the second object into it and then serialize the list containing these two object arrays.

If you have a third object to serialize you have to again read the `java.util.ArrayList` from the file and append to it the third object and so on.

Just a note: it is better to initially save the first object array into a `java.util.ArrayList` even though you have only one single object array.